# Formatting of flash feedback messages in Apache Wicket

Tags: apache, format, wicket

Is it possible to format (internationalized) flash feedback messages in Apache Wicket? Specifically, I need to break a longer error message to separate lines but can not find a way to do it...? (html tags do no work and any other way to include a new line either)

---

Edit

```
 public static void messageError(Page page, String messageText) {
    page.error(messageText);
}
```

The error method accepts only a string not a model, so `setEscapeModelStrings(false)` does not work here.

Comment: The `error()` method accepts `Serializable` - https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/b0eee3b7e67d6a829398b3baab43b32db3d0b561/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/Component.java#L1214

Comment: You need to call `FeedbackPanel.setEscapeModelStrings(false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use HTML tags to format your message (es: `<br>`) but you need to invoke `setEscapeModelStrings(false)` on the component in order to avoid html escaping

Comment: you should call setEscapeModelStrings(false) on the component you use to display messages. I guess you use something like FeedbackPanel in your page:

add(new FeedbackPanel("feedbackMessage").setEscapeModelStrings(false));